# Access Multiple Web Sites Hosted on single server on local network from workstations

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, intranet

I am trying to set up a secondary web site hosted on our local domain controller running IIS-8. 
I already have one site working successfully thought our network, the default site.

I have successfully got the second one to work on the localhost (the domain controller Server 2012-R2), but I can't seem to access it from any of the other workstations on our network.

I added the new site.
Set the binding to `IP address:192.168.1.1, Port:80, Host Name:dyo.mysite.com`

I have modifed *C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* to show `192.168.1.1 dyo.mysite.com`, and I have added an alias to the forward lookup Zone in the DNS Manager. (`Name:byo.mysite.com, FQND:byo.mysite.com.mydc.com, Target Host: 192.168.1.1`)

I can't seem to access the site from any of the network work stations. I have tried many combinations of addresses, http://byo.mysite.com, 192.168.1.1/byo.mysite.com, \mydc\byo.mysite.com, etc.

I would imagine that I am probably missing something simple. I just don't know it is. 
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup dyo.mysite.com` on one of the workstations?

Answer (score 0):

To get your server accessed from other workstation.  You have to promise

1. Your IIS site can be accessed via IP address directly.
2. the client workstation is using your DNS
3. Your client workstation is not bypassing your DNS server by .pac proxy

So could you get access the website via IP address by disabling default website and set the site to unassigned IP or 192.168.1.1 with null domain name?

If you want to access the website via **byo.mysite.com**. Then you **shouldn't** set FQDN like **byo.mysite.com.mydc.com**.  because Web browser will never consider **byo.mysite.com** as an alias but a **different server**. That's why When you set FQDN like **byo.myDC.com**, you could get work by access **http://dyo** and you could also access website via **byo.mysite.com.mydc.com** but fail with **byo.mysite.com**.

**How to set DNS correctly**

To get it work, please create an new primary **Forward Loopup Zone** named **mysite.com**. Then create a new HOST(A) record to map to your machine name like dc.mysite.com and 192.168.1.1. Then create an Alias(CNAME) called www to map to this A NAME. Then the FQDN will be www.mysite.com.

Finally bind your IIS site and access the website should work.

PS: Please make sure your other workstation is not using a proxy.